# Python - TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.5

Trying my hand at Python inheritance. I need your help on how to fix an error.

I have 2 classes: Person (super class )& Contact (sub class).

I get the following error when trying to run Contact:

```
        "Contact.py", line 3, in <module>
            class Contact(Person):
        TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Thanks in advance

Below is my code:

```
class Person:
      __name=""
      __age=0

      def __init__(self, name, age):
          self.__name = name
          self.__age = age

      def set_name(self, name):
          self.__name = name

      def set_age(selfself, age):
          self.__age = age

      def get_name(self):
          return self.__name

      def get_age(selfself):
          return self.__age

      def  getInfo(self):
        return "Name is: {} - Age is: {}".format(self.__name, self.__age)

        # ----------------------------------------------------

    import Person
            class Contact(Person):
        __method=""

        def __init__(self, name, age, method):
            super().__init__(name, age)
            self.__method = method



        def set_method(self, method):
            self.__method = method

        def get__method(self):
            return self.__method

        def getInfo(self):
            return "Name is: {} - Age is: {} - Contact Info: {}".format(self.__name, self.__age, self.__method)


    person2 = Contact("Adam Smith", 19, "Email: adam.smith@abcde.net")
    print(person2.getInfo())
```

Comment: `Person` is a module, not a class. What is that `import` statement doing there? Do you define `Person` in a file named `Person.py`? If so, you need to use `class Contact(Person.Person)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the indentation is messed up!

If Person is in a separate file, import the file name without extension, like this:

```
class Person:

  def __init__(self, name, age):
      self.__name = name
      self.__age = age

  def set_name(self, name):
      self.__name = name

  def set_age(self, age):
      self.__age = age

  def get_name(self):
      return self.__name

  def get_age(self):
      return self.__age

  def getInfo(self):
      return "Name is: {} - Age is: {}".format(self.__name, self.__age)

    # ----------------------------------------------------

from person import Person # assumed your Person class is in person.py

class Contact(Person):
    __method=""

    def __init__(self, name, age, method):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.__method = method

    def set_method(self, method):
        self.__method = method

    def get__method(self):
        return self.__method

    def getInfo(self):
        return "Name is: {} - Age is: {} - Contact Info: {}".format(self.get_name(), self.get_age(), self.__method)


person2 = Contact("Adam Smith", 19, "Email: adam.smith@abcde.net")
print(person2.getInfo())
```

Access the parent class's private fields through its methods.